# Python application builder/packager

Tags: python, qt, build, executable

I'm writing a program in python using PySide(PyQt) and I want to distribute it to friends and family when I'm finished. I have looked at other posts in stack overflow, but I can't seem to find any good ones showing an easy solution(command line or otherwise) that will create an executable for my program to be run on other computers who don't have python or Qt etc. I'm running Ubuntu right now, however I would like to be able to package for windows as well.

Edit: I wrote all the Qt interface in my python script, so the whole project is contained in the one script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to create executables for scripts using PyQt4 under Windows without any trouble. Though I have not used it on Linux, it claims Linux (and OSX) support as well. You may need to create your Windows binaries in a Windows system or through Wine according to the [FAQ](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/FAQ):

> - Can I package Windows binaries while running under Linux?
>
> No, this
>   is not supported. Please use  Wine for this, PyInstaller runs fine in
>   Wine. You may also want to have a look at  this thread in the
>   mailinglist. In version 1.4 we had build in some support for this, but
>   it showed to work only half. It would require some Windows system on
>   another partition and would only work for pure Python programs. As
>   soon as you want a decent GUI (gtk, qt, wx), you would need to install
>   Windows libraries anyhow. So it's much easier to just use Wine.

Comment: I have Win7, so i can make under windows if needed